# Method not found: Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

Tags: google-drive-api, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have a Xamarin Forms project that is using a portable library. Through NuGet, I have my portable library and my Win 8.1 project updated with v1.25.0 for Google.Apis.Auth.

When I run my Win 8.1 project, I get the following error.

An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.String, System.Threading.CancellationToken, Google.Apis.Util.Store.IDataStore, Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ICodeReceiver)'.

It appears that the projects are referencing assemblies that have different signatures for the Authorize method. The portable project has optional paramaters, that I am not specifying values to. But the Win 8.1 project's version of that method doesn't have the optional paramaters.

I am fairly new to this so I am not familar with how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None);
```